# MKStoreKit -isSubscriptionActive always return False

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am Using MKStoreKit for autorenewable subscription.

On Button's TouchUpInside method I am using following code..

```
if([[MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:kSubscriptionMonthlyIdentifier]){
  //access to subscription feature
}else{
  //ask user to buy
}
```

It always returns me false. And ask user to buy.

When I tried to buy again it shows me that `You are already subscribed`.

- Is there something that I am doing wrong?
- Is there any other method to check if subscription is active or not.
- How should I know that subscription is renewed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should initialize MKStoreKit by adding `[MKStoreManager sharedManager];` in your applicationDidFinishLaunching.

2) You should check, that you correctly fill `MKStoreKitConfigs.plist`:

you must add your subscriptions in-app ids to `Subscriptions` dictionary (in format: `"subs id" - "subs duration"`).

In apple documentation you could find info about auto-renewable subs:
every renewal of the auto-renewable subscription new transaction would be generated and send to your application. In theory, MKStoreKit must take care about all this stuff, and `isSubscriptionActive` should work.

Also, you could add button for restoring previous purchases. So, in your case, when user press buy button before calling `-isSubscriptionActive` call `-restorePreviousTransactions`, or you can add this button, so user can restore previous transaction^ if he already has bought subscription.

You could add observers for this notifications:

```
#define kSubscriptionsPurchasedNotification @"MKStoreKitSubscriptionsPurchased"
#define kSubscriptionsInvalidNotification @"MKStoreKitSubscriptionsInvalid"
```

First notification MKStoreKit generate, when Subscription was renewed (or purchased), second one - when renewing failed.

Comment: Thanks for input

 1. & 2. Already Done. I can purchase product Id and also get notification when purchase done or failed. :(

How can I know when auto subscription is done?

Comment: Have i answered your question, or what did you mean by "How can I know when auto subscription is done", may be i've misunderstand you?

Comment: but -restorePreviosTransactions asks user to login.

Comment: Yes, because of this it's better to add special button for restoring previous transaction - or ask user for his password twice.

Comment: but when user subscribed It should auto renew. Not every time ask user for login..

Comment: Yes, but if user will reinstall your app, you must provide a possibility to restore purchases, and also restore your subsctption

Comment: If user reinstall app, there is an option to restore purchases. But My problem is when subscription is over app must auto renew, should not ask user for password unless he logged out from settings. Subscription should auto renew when its over unless user logged out.

Comment: In theory, MKStoreKit must care about renewing of subscription. But, when you test your app in sandbox, subscription automatically renews only 6 times, and 1 month of subscription = 1 hour when you work in sandbox

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746286/566431
1 month = 5mins. And subscription renews 5 times for one test user in sendbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/issues/66) on the MKStoreKit GitHub that might be related to what you are experiencing. The people in that thread claim that after the app is initialized MKStoreKit always returns NO for `isSubscriptionActive`. It seems they were able to successfully use a previous release of MKStoreKit, though. You might want to try that.